# What is a short code?

Tags: shortcode

I am new to WordPress and I've seen this term passed around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Shortcode" is a user friendly way of inserting various WordPress plugins/scripts into a page without having to know a lot of fancy HTML/JavaScript/PHP in order to make it happen.

Take, for example, embedding an mp3 file into a post on a hosted WordPress site. Instead of having to setup the proper code for a flash player or fiddle with some fancy JavaScript, you can use the following shortcode in the editor. You don't even switch to HTML mode...

```
[audio: http://www.pathtomyaudio.com/song.mp3]
```

...and WordPress does the rest for you.

You'll find a lot of plugins for WordPress (such as Contact Form 7 and others) use this convention.

Comment: For another example, the simple shortcode `[gallery]` inserts a nicely formatted grid of all of the images attached to a post. It has several optional parameters but it can be used just as I typed it.

Answer (score 2):

Not long ago i posted a nice explanation: [**Shotcodes because its shorter!**](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/shotcodes-because-its-shorter)
It covers in short:

- What shortcodes are.
- How to use shortcodes.
- How to define your own.
- How to use them in widgets.

Worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

These are [WordPress.com specific shortcodes](http://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/), but they give you an idea of the power of using them.